# Measuring perimeter and area of QGIS polygons and middle point coordinates

Tags: qgis, shapefile, coordinates

I have >1000 shapefile polygons on a QGIS project that I need to find the perimeter and area of. They're located on a world map, and I can't seem to get the geometry outputs for the measurements in metres. I also need the coordinates for the centre point of each polygon, any idea how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want measurements in meters (area, length etc.) usually you need to first convert to from the original projection to a local UTM zone. If your study area spans multiple UTM zones then choose an appropriate regional projection.

1. **Convert projection**: On the layers panel right click your polygon layer and click Export > Save Features As > then change the CRS to your local UTM zone > Ok (exports a new layer in UTM projection).
2. **Calculate perimeter and area**: Click on your new UTM layer and open the field calculator. In the output field name type 'my_area' then in the expression box type '$area' (no quotes). Click ok and area will appear in field attribute table. Repeate this process for perimeter, but substitute $length for $area.
3. **Polygon Centroid**: Go back to the layer panel. highlight the target layer and then click Vector> Geometry Tools > Centroid.

That should give you what you're looking for. Please read up on Cartesian coordinates, geometry calculations and GIS projections. If this is your first time doing this I recommend checking some of your calculations manually in Google Earth to make sure everything worked ok.

Comment: Are you sure that `$length` will give you the lenght of the perimeter of a polygon? Shouldn't it be `$perimeter` or `$length($perimeter)`?

Answer (score 1):

You should do the following. If some things are new for you, probably you should spare some time to learn those.

1. Go to Project settings `Project >> Properties >> General` and change the unit of distance and area into meters and square meters, respectively.
2. Open the attribute table of the polygon shapefile for which you want to perform these calculations.
3. Toggle on Edit mode
4. Open field calculator. Check `Create a new field`. Make `Output field type` as `Decimal number (real)`. Write a reasonable field name.
5. In the field calculator, write `$area` in the expression tab and press OK. A new field (column) will appear now with area calculations in your desired units.
6. Similarly, repeat these steps and write `$perimeter` in the expression tab.